# CreateView switch model

Tags: django, create-view

i have a problem with my CreateView.
I wish I could have two different models that change based on the url it finds.
I also have problems with success_url, I don't know how to pass it a parameter.

url.py

```
path('crea-<tipo>', CreaView.as_view(), name="crea")
```

views.py

```
class CreaView(StaffMixin, CreateView, tipo):
  if tipo == "gruppo":
    model = Gruppi
  elif tipo == "esercizio":
    model = Esercizio
  fields = '__all__'
  template_name = 'staff/crea.html'
  success_url = '/backoffice/lista/<tipo>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juste create two different CreateView:

```
GruppiCreateView(StaffMixin, CreateView):
     model = Gruppi
     fields = '__all__'
     template_name = 'staff/crea.html'
     success_url = '/backoffice/lista/gruppi'

EsercizioCreateView(StaffMixin, CreateView):
    model = Esercizio
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'staff/crea.html'
    success_url = '/backoffice/lista/esercizio'
```

Comment: and for url.py do I always have to create two routes?

Comment: Yes, in this case this the best solution. Unless you have dozens of create view to duplicate, there no need here for optimization.

Comment: okay, thank you very much for your help, you have been very kind =)